# Postgresql 10: Can not establish DB connection

Tags: postgresql, psql, dbeaver

I have created a new database and user in Postgresql 10 named 'reportingdashboardproject' and 'repadmin' respectively. I used the following commands to create and grant privileges:

```
postgres=# create database reportingdashboardproject;
postgres=# create user repadmin with encrypted password '<password>';
postgres=# grant all privileges on database reportingdashboardproject to repadmin;
psql=# grant all privileges on database reportingdashboardproject to repadmin ;
```

I get this in response when trying to start my Express.js server with a db connection URI using the above:

```
FATAL password authentication failed for user repadmin
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
const dbConfig = {
  operatorsAliases: false
};

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/reportingdashboardproject', dbConfig); //also tried using repadmin:<password>, failed.
```

I get the same error when trying to open the connection through DBeaver (port 5432)

I then tried using user: postgres and password: postgres, or empty. None of these combos worked. On the empty password attempt I saw this:

```
The server requested password based authentication, but no password was provided
```

Partial Db list (template0 and template1 were there too):

```
postgres=# \l

  Name            |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
---------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres                  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 reportingdashboardproject | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
```

User list:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 repadmin  |                                                            | {}
```

I have tried explicitly granting privileges to the superuser also:

```
postgres=# grant all privileges on database reportingdashboardproject to postgres;
GRANT
```

Could it be a sudo/permissions issue of some kind?

```
postgres=# \q
could not save history to file "/opt/PostgreSQL/10/.psql_history": Permission denied
```

Not sure what to troubleshoot next. Thanks for any guidance.

EDIT: Adding the following:

Inside `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf` I see this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_authid where rolname='repadmin' \gx
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------------------------------------
rolname        | repadmin
rolsuper       | f
rolinherit     | t
rolcreaterole  | f
rolcreatedb    | f
rolcanlogin    | t
rolreplication | f
rolbypassrls   | f
rolconnlimit   | -1
rolpassword    | md529562c8706ed74d108795a4e9a37f261
rolvaliduntil  |
```

Comment: Check you `pg_hba.conf` and the property `listen_addreses` inside `postgresql.conf`

Comment: `#listen_addresses = 'localhost' 
port = 5433 `
Tried connecting with port 5433. Same error

Comment: Yes, on attempts 1 and 2 I entered the passwords. On try 3 I did not:
```owner@G700:~$ psql -U repadmin -h localhost -d reportingdashboardproject
Password for user repadmin: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "repadmin"

owner@G700:~$ psql -U postgres -h localhost -d reportingdashboardproject 
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

owner@G700:~$ psql -U postgres -h localhost -d reportingdashboardproject
Password for user postgres: 
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
owner@G700:~$```

Comment: Ok, done..........

Comment: Sorry, it was there but I mis-copied it. It was blank as shown in the post now

Comment: It looks totally OK. I'm out of ideas and deleted my previous comments.

Comment: Except if you have a connection pooler like pgBouncer with its own list of users. See https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html#authentication-file-format

Comment: No I don't believe I'm using pgBouncer or anything like that

Comment: What message shows up in the server log file?  When client authentication fails, the server does not tell the client everything it knows, for obvious reasons.  You have to look in the server log file to get the whole story.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling postgres and that seems to have fixed it, will remember that next time though